# My flutter website is displaying blank page on mobile browser

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have created a project using flutter web but after generating the release build, it works fine on desktop browsers but displays a blank (white) page on mobile browsers.

**Note that**: I also have tried url_stratergy and I am using Flutter version 1.26.0-17-pre. Below is the output of my flutter doctor
[image: flutter doctor]

I have generated the release build using the following command:

```
flutter build web --release
```

You can also visit the website to verify the issue at [HerAmigo](https://www.heramigo.live).

Looking forward to your help and suggestion!
Thanks
Ayesha Iftikhar

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the console of the browser?

Comment: In the mobile browser, it shows nothing on the console.

Comment: You can try to run on a mobile device by running the app on release mode.

Comment: @PratikButani will try that

Comment: @PratikButani doesn't work

Comment: Do you find a way to fix this? I have the same problem and I see your site working well now.

Comment: I just used the accepted answer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try running this command. This will repair and fix the pub cache.

```sh
flutter pub cache repair
```